# Plot two variables in one single y axis

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot two different variables in one single axis. However, when I use twinx() the result is 2 different y axis...

Here is the code:

```
def diffplot(self, xAxis, y1Axis, y2Axis):

    x = xAxis
    y1 = y1Axis
    y2 = y2Axis

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax1.plot(x,y1)
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x,y2,'o')
    plt.show()
```

Yes... "self" because it's inside a class.

So, how can I plot y1 and y2 in one single y-axis?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you put a picture of what you are getting someplace we can see and link to an example of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `twiny` instead of `twinx`.

Comment: I believe twiny share the y axis with two different x axis... but that's not what I need. My goal is to make one single y axis with two different variables AND a single x-axis. (e.g y1 = temperature, y2 = average_temperature, x = hour)
but thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you want a single x axis and a single y axis, does `ax1.plot(x, y1, x, y2)` do what you want?

Comment: Yeap... I fixed the dimension error, but the graph is basically the same. I was thinking more about something as in: http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html

but only with 'velocity' and 'temperature' (and the x-axis, 'distance')

Comment: In the example you point to, there are *multiple* y axis, not one. I am afraid I can't help if you don't provide an exact description of what you want.

Comment: I see... But the thing is that at first I thought to put different variables in the same axis, but I don't think that it's possible, so I would just go with what we see in matplotlib examples.

Sorry about this